# Filtering a nested object depending on a key array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been provided with an *object* and an *array*, I need to filter out the object in such a way that it contains only the nodes where either the key or the value matches with the given keys in array.
*For e.g.,*

Array containing keys - `['student1', 'STU', 'LMN', 'student4']`

**INPUT**

```
{
    student1: {
        name: 'ABC',
        roll: 17,
    },
    student2: {
        name: 'LMN',
        roll: 16
    },
    student3: {
        name: 'MNO',
        roll: 15
    },
    student4: {
        name: 'PQR',
        roll: 16
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    student1: {
        name: 'ABC',
        roll: 17,
    },
    student2: {
        name: 'LMN',
        roll: 16
    },
    student4: {
        name: 'PQR',
        roll: 16
    }
}
```

**INPUT**

```
{
    student1: {
        name: 'ABC',
        roll: 17,
        friends: {
            student5: {},
            student6: {}
        }
    },
    student2: {
        name: 'LMN',
        roll: 16
    },
    student3: {
        name: 'MNO',
        roll: 15,
        friends: {
            student7: {
                name: 'STU'
            }
        }
    },
    student4: {
        name: 'PQR',
        roll: 16
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
    student1: {
        name: 'ABC',
        roll: 17,
        friends: {
            student5: {},
            student6: {}
        }
    },
    student2: {
        name: 'LMN',
        roll: 16
    },
    student3: {
        name: 'MNO',
        roll: 15,
        friends: {
            student7: {
                name: 'STU'
            }
        }
    },
    student4: {
        name: 'PQR',
        roll: 16
    }
}
```

**INPUT**

```
{
    student5: {
        name: 'EFG',
        roll: 10,
        friends: {
            student1: {},
            student2: {}
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
    student5: {
        name: 'EFG',
        roll: 10,
        friends: {
            student1: {}
        }
    }
}
```

***Explanation :***

Keys are `'student1', 'student4', 'STU' and 'LMN'`, so we parse the entire object and wherever we get either the key or the value from the object matching those keys, we include that in resultant object else we discard it.
Also, if we get a key in the object matching the keys provided in the array, we do not need to check the inside of that particular entry. *For e.g.,* in case of 'student1', since it's included in the keys array, we do not need to check what it contains, we can blindly include it in target object.

**NOTE:** *The object can be deeply nested also.*

**MY APPROACH**

I was trying to parse the entire object and filter out the entries depending on whether it's present or not, but it doesn't seem to give correct results,

```
const containsKey = (obj, arr = []) => {
  return (
    obj &&
    typeof obj === "object" &&
    (arr.some((key) => key in obj) ||
      arr.indexOf(obj[targetKey]) > -1 ||
      Object.values(obj).filter((obj) => {
        return containsKey(obj, arr);
      }))
  );
};

Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) =>
      containsKey({ [k]: v }, arr)
    )
  );
```

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses three functions:

- `toList`: a recursive function that flattens any object into a one-dimensional array.
- `inList`: a function that returns a boolean to indicate whether or not one of the items in the resulting list is in the array of keys `keys`
- `filObject`: a function that "filters" the given object depending on the boolean returned

```js
const keys = ['student1', 'STU', 'LMN', 'student4'],
      input1 =  { student1: { name: 'ABC', roll: 17, }, student2: { name: 'LMN', roll: 16 }, student3: { name: 'MNO', roll: 15 }, student4: { name: 'PQR', roll: 16 } },
      input2 = { student1: { name: 'ABC', roll: 17, friends: { student5: {}, student6: {} } }, student2: { name: 'LMN', roll: 16 }, student3: { name: 'MNO', roll: 15, friends: { student7: { name: 'STU' } } }, student4: { name: 'PQR', roll: 16 } },
      
      toList = o => Object.entries(o).flat().map(
          v =>
          typeof(v) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v) ?
              toList(v) :
              v
      )
      .flat(),
      inList = (list, o) => toList(o).some(k => list.includes(k)),
      
      filObject = (list,obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce(
          (acc,[key,value]) => 
          inList(list,{[key]:value}) ? {...acc,[key]:value} : acc, {}
      );
      
      
console.log( filObject(keys,input1) );

console.log( filObject(keys,input2) );
```

**Updated version ...**

The function `filObject` in this version uses recursion to filter deeper parts where the `key` fails the test but the `value` passes. The line `inList(list,{[key]:value}) ? {...acc,[key]:value} : acc, {}` was replaced by **`list.includes(key) ? {...acc,[key]:value} : inList(list,value) ? {...acc,[key]:filObject(list,value)} : acc, {}`**.

```js
const keys = ['student1', 'STU', 'LMN', 'student4'],
      input1 =  { student1: { name: 'ABC', roll: 17, }, student2: { name: 'LMN', roll: 16 }, student3: { name: 'MNO', roll: 15 }, student4: { name: 'PQR', roll: 16 } },
      input2 = { student1: { name: 'ABC', roll: 17, friends: { student5: {}, student6: {} } }, student2: { name: 'LMN', roll: 16 }, student3: { name: 'MNO', roll: 15, friends: { student7: { name: 'STU' } } }, student4: { name: 'PQR', roll: 16 } },
      input3 = { student5: { name: 'EFG', roll: 10, friends: { student1: {}, student2: {} } } },
      
      toList = o => Object.entries(o).flat().map(
          v =>
          typeof(v) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v) ?
              toList(v) :
              v
      )
      .flat(),
      inList = (list, o) => toList(o).some(k => list.includes(k)),
      
      filObject = (list,obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce(
          (acc,[key,value]) => 
          [key,value].some(p => list.includes(p)) ? {...acc,[key]:value} :
          inList(list,value) ? {...acc,[key]:filObject(list,value)} : acc, {}
      );


console.log( filObject(keys,input1) );

console.log( filObject(keys,input2) );

console.log( filObject(keys,input3) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Worked for the given 2 scenarios, but it doesn't filter out in nested object. For example, I added 3rd scenario in my question, it outputs both students student1 and student2 objects, but that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I see the scenario you just added. That completely changes the question. Your two original examples showed that you were only interested in filtering at first level. To go deeper, you may have to take a recursive approach.

Comment: Further to my point above, example 2 is not consistent with example 3. Why is it alright to retain `student5` and `student6` (properties of `friends`) in example 2 but not `student2` in example 3? Maybe you want to rethink the whole question?

Comment: Hi, I already added that explanation in the question, maybe it wasn't evident, my bad. I provided this in the question itself- Also, if we get a key in the object matching the keys provided in the array, we do not need to check the inside of that particular entry. For e.g., in case of 'student1', since it's included in the keys array, we do not need to check what it contains, we can blindly include it in target object.
In case if we get a match at first level, we don't consider the inner object, but if we don't get a match and we dig deeper then we only include filtered object.

Comment: @FrostedCupcake, please take a look at the updated version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your updated answer, for first and second scenario, now I am not getting anything in student2, it gives an empty object.

Comment: I see now what I overlooked; a test on whether `value` is in keys in `filObject`. Having resolved that there's no way `roll: 16` can be retained (filtered in); it would break the existing logic - in examples 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply iterate through `Object.entries(object)` and check if the key or value of entry exists in the keys array. If a value is another object repeat the same for it.

```
function checkNested(object, keys) {
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)){
    if(
        (keys.includes(key) || keys.includes(value)) 
      &&
      (value != null && typeof value == 'object' && checkNested(value, keys))
    ) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function filterWithKeys(object, keys) {
    const result = {};
  
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)){
    if(
        (keys.includes(key) || keys.includes(value)) 
      &&
      (value != null && typeof value == 'object' && checkNested(value, keys))
    ) {
        result[key] = value;
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I didn't downvote it, also it doesn't work for the scenarios mentioned in the question.